a.$|f(x)| < 5$ and b. $f(x) f'(x) \geq \sin x$ for all $x \in (0, \infty)$. Does $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$ exist?
Problem statement:- Let $f$ be a real-valued differentiable function on $(0, \infty)$ satisfying:
a. $|f(x)| < 5$
and 
b. $f(x) f'(x) \geq \sin x$ for all $x \in (0, \infty)$.
Does $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$ exist?
my approach-
Consider $F(x) = f^2(x) + 2 \cos x$ defined on $(0, \infty)$. Then by (a),
$$|F(x)| < |f(x)|^2 + 2|\cos x| < 5^2 + 2.$$
By (b),$$
F'(x) = 2f(x) f'(x) - 2 \sin x \geq 0, \quad \forall x \in (0, \infty),
$$
implying that $F(x)$ is an increasing function.
so now we have two informations  $1. |F(x)|< 27 $ and $F'(x) \geq 0, \quad\forall  x \in (0, \infty) $
now how do I proceed further? How do I use these information to find the limit? please give some ideas and lastly if you find an error in what I wrote please politely put it down in comment. Thanks!
edit- I forgot to mention since $F(x)$ is bounded and its increasing, can we say it would converge by monotone-convergence theorem?(I'm new to advanced calculus)

Yes, $\lim_{x \to \infty} F(x)$ exists and is finite because the function is increasing and bounded.

Assume the limit of $f$ at infinities exists to the contrary. First assume $f'(x)$ exists, by boundness of $f$, $f'\to0$. So $f(x)\to+\infty$ as $x\to+\infty$ for it to greater than $1$ (so is $\sin x$), contradicting boundness. Hence $f'$ has to have no limit at infinity. Now try to see if some experts can continue (i have no idea)

$F$ has  a limit as at $\infty$. If $f$ had  a limit at $\infty$  then $2\cos x =F(x)-[f(x)]^{2} $ would have  a limit at $\infty$ which is a  contradiction. Hence, $\lim f(x)$ cannot exist under the given hypothesis.

how did you take equality? In problems strict inequality is given

I am just using your definition of $F(x)$. @AlokRajSingh

sorry you are right thanks

Just let $f(x)=2\sin\frac x2$.
a. $|f(x)|=\left|2\sin\frac x2\right|\le2<5$.
b. $f(x)f'(x)=2\sin\frac x2\cdot 2\cos\frac x2 \cdot\frac12=2\sin\frac x2\cos \frac x2=\sin x\ge\sin x$.
Hence $f(x)=2\sin\frac x2$ satisfies the conditions. However $f(x)=2\sin \frac x2$ has no limit as $x\to\infty$.

umm but to be honest this letting thing would not be considered as legitimate method because there might be any other function satisfying the following criterions and has a limit,

@AlokRajSingh Indeed. This answer is an example, not a proof that $f$ will never have a limit.
